# simple terminal javascript chess game not understanding the error

Tags: javascript, arrays

Tried to create a function to move a "chess" piece and Im not too sure what is happening. any help is appreciated

```
var board = [
    ['R', 'N', 'B', 'Q', 'K', 'B', 'N', 'R'],
    ['P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P', 'P'],
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
    ['p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p', 'p'],
    ['r', 'n', 'b', 'q', 'k', 'b', 'n', 'r'],
];


var printBoard = function () {
    console.log(board.join('\n') + '\n\n');
};

printBoard(); // printBoard is a function that takes no arguments since it just prints a board from the array

var moveMe = function (fromX, fromY, toX, toY) {

    board[toY][toX] = [fromY][fromX];
    board[fromY][fromX] = ' ';
    printBoard();
};
moveMe(1, 1, 1, 2);
```

Comment: Can you provide anything more around what is currently happening. And what you expect to happen?

Comment: Looks like something's missing here: `board[toY][toX] = [fromY][fromX];`

Comment: sorry, the 'P' below the N at the top left should move forward one space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
board[toY][toX] = [fromY][fromX];
```

should be:

```
board[toY][toX] = board[fromY][fromX];
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/keropi/1/edit?js,console,output)***

Comment: omg I feel like an idiot.  thanks.

Comment: @imnothardcore I know that feeling ;) Happy coding